# How to prevent Rails 3.2.2 to create a .js file everytime I change a .coffee file in the assets/javascripts/ directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Every time I change a .coffee file in the development mode, Rails creates a corresponding .js file in the same /javascripts directory.  With the result that Rails ends up processing both the files and therefore instead of firing an event once, I end getting that event firing twice.  I have to remember to manually delete the .js file so I get the correct and anticipated behavior.

My question is: how can I prevent Rails from generating the .js file in the first place?  Is it not supposed to compile the .coffee file in memory in the development mode?  when I delete the generated .js file, I get the correct and anticipated behavior?

Thanks.

Bharat

Comment: Maybe I'm not following you, but are you sure events are firing twice because of coffee script compilation?  CS complilation only results in one set of .js files loaded at runtime.  Perhaps there is something in your project that is causing jquery (and/or another .js) to be loaded twice.  Did you check your header for this?  Are you having this behavior in a fresh new project?  Maybe you have a dup being loaded from somewhere else (such as public).

Comment: To add to what Ken said, where is the JS file that actually runs when you delete the one in your /javascripts directory? Coffeescript has to get compiled somewhere...

Comment: The way I know that the events (change to be specific) is being fired twice is that I have an alert attached as a test to a select box.  Instead of showing it once, it gets shown twice.  Once I delete the generated .js file, i.e., type_well.js.js (generated as a result of changing type_well.js.coffee file).  If I delete type_well.js.js file then the alert only gets displayed once which is the correct behavior

Comment: Hi Ken, you said  Did you check your header for this? - How do I check the header? I checked, there is no public/assets directory in my project.

Comment: Hello Ken,  Thanks for your incredibly detailed response.  I think I am fairly close to resolution.  I had an equally lengthy follow-up.  So I ended up editing your answer and adding my follow up response since I could not find a way to answer (or respond).  Stackoverflow shows that it is being reviewed by the moderators and will be published soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `<head>` section of your page.  You check it by viewing the source of the page when running your app.  If you do so I would bet that you will see one or more .js files that are included twice.  Make sure you don't have unnecessary javascript_include_tags somewhere in your views.

Unless you changed the default require statements in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, any javascript files that are in there are being automatically included as long as your layout is set to include them (which it is by default).

Specifically, if you have this line in your application.js:

```
//= require_tree .
```

or

```
//= require_directory .
```

That will cause all .js files in the app/assets/javascripts directory (and sub directories if you have require_tree) to be included where you have the following in your page:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Usually this will be the case as it will be in your default layout (in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`).

So if they are already included in your layout you want to make sure you're not including them again any other way.

Another thing you could try is to remove the include from your layout and then just include javascript files manually per view using `javascript_include_tag`.

Comment: Thanks you for your incredibly detailed response.  Here is what I did.  I deleted the //= require_tree and specifically mentioned the files to be included, e.g., //= require type_wells for instance in the application.js file and things started to work as intended.